# Is the elasticsearch relevance score an ordinal or interval value?

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

In other words, is the difference between scores of 0.7 and 0.8 the same as the difference between scores of 0.5 and 0.6? Or is the 0.1 difference meaningless, not a measure of anything?

Answer (score -1):

My guess: it's an ordinal data and it depends on the type of query

Have a look at the theory behind relevance: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

Comment: I am working on that guess as well, but I'd like to find out for certain.

Comment: Also, scores are normalized per query.  So if you were planning to compare scores across queries, read this first:  http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages